# How to show a PNG image on the camera display and make it appear on the picture?

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm not lazy, been looking for this for some time and noting.

I want to display a image in the camera and make that pic actually be save with the pic.

For exemple, I want to make an app that show a funny hat image on the camera display, so the user can aim the camera, place the hat into someone head, take the pic and most important, the final file must integrate the hat into the pic like one file.

Any ideas how can I start this?

I'll def vote positive if get this answer

Answer (score 0):

Please go through surface view that would help